# why collapsible and expandable image not display?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I am adding the data statically it show collapsible and expandable image (+ and -).but here i add in static data in left panel

http://jsfiddle.net/Nm5br/1/

But I apply same concept while adding the data dynamically .it don't display the + and - sign  why ?
http://jsfiddle.net/Nm5br/10/

I try this code.

```
var updateOutput = function(e) {
    var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
        output = list.data('output');

    if (window.JSON) {
        output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));
    }
    else {
        output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
    }
};

// activate Nestable for list 1
$('#nestable').nestable({group: 1}).on('change', updateOutput);

// output initial serialised data
updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code working dynamically [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/Nm5br/11/).

```
<ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
        <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>                
           <ol class="dd-list" id="testcase">

           </ol>
    </li>
 </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing code in the 2nd version... there is a function bound to `$('#nestable-menu')` that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the HTML that gets rendered by your first fiddle, it seems as if you are missing some markup (in the second fiddle) that you need to actually see expand/collapse buttons.

When you are injecting the html with:

```
.append('<li class="dd-item" data-id="3"><div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div></li>'
```

you are missing `<button>` tags that are rendered in your first fiddle.  This is why you do not see those images in your second fiddle.

Hope that helps.